# Is it possible to get reverse output from method like this? If so how?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have tried to make a loop which outputs numbers 1-10 in reverse order, but I fail to get it reversed.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {

    console.log(i);

    }
}
```

Here is the output:
1
3
5
7
9

Output should look like:
9
7
5
3
1

Comment: What are you looking for? Changing the logic to execute this in reverse, or leaving the loop intact and somehow make the normal output it produces show up in the opposite way?

Comment: I wnat to keep the loop but make it to show up in opposite way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just start from 10 and count backwards?

```js
for (i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {

    console.log(i);

    }
}
```